# Fuzzily: cannot get it to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the directions from the gem's GitHub repo:

I added fuzzily to my gem file and ran rake db:install. Fuzzily 0.3.3 was successfully installed.

I created a app/models/fuzzily.rb file:

```
class Trigram < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Fuzzily::Model
end
```

I then created a migration for it:

```
class AddTrigramModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  extend Fuzzily::Migration
end
```

And ran: rake db:migrate, which created a trigrams table with the fields: id, trigram, score, owner_id, owner_type, fuzzy_field

I then modified my app/models/organization.rb and added the following:

```
fuzzily_searchable :org_name
```

I saved all my work and started the console:

```
rails c
```

then:

```
Lobbyist.connection
```

Followed by:

```
Lobbyist.bulk_update_fuzzy_name
```

To which I am getting an error message: undefined method .bulk_update_fuzzy_name

My environment is:

```
Ruby 2.1.5
Rails 4.2.1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` part in `bulk_update_fuzzy_name` is actually the name of the searchable field, so in your case it would be `Lobbyist.bulk_update_fuzzy_org_name`. The same applies to other method calls in the readme.